# Highcharts not rendering data after build is deployed

Tags: highcharts, angular-highcharts

Highcharts is not displaying graphs once deployed but the same is working fine on local host.

I am using Highcharts version 9.1.2 for angular, following their documentation I created a scatter graph which is working perfectly on local host, but once the project is deployed the graphs are blank only the axis are seen. I am unable to debug it as it works fine on local host and gives issues only after deployment.

Comment: What errors are you getting on the page? It seems that you may have missed a id that is unique so it knows where to render it or called in the highcharts library

Comment: This seems to be more like a data issue.  Please, check if you get any errors and try to reproduce your chart in the online demo so that I could test it. You can start here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-ias8hs?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It was working previously it is has stopped all of a sudden there is no changes in the format of the data been sent

Comment: Yeah sure will develop a POC with same code that is been used in the project. @magdalena

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved it was occurring due to different time zones set for the project and the for the server.